# What is the difference between 'looked at' and 'looked over at'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

I read the sentence "He put a hand on Bran's shoulder, and Bran looked over at his bastard brother."

Here, they both were on their horses.

I've seen this usage of 'over' before but couldn't exactly get its importance.

Comment: **Over** is an adverb = across (a distance or space that is implied between the subject, and the object that is being "looked at".)

Comment: (1) *I looked at the book in my hand.* (2) *I looked **over** at the building across the street.* They can often be used interchangeably, but *over* isn't used when the thing being looked at is very close and there is nothing that intervenes between it and the eye. Don't ask to have "very close" defined by a specific distance. It's a matter of loose usage.

Comment: Too many words. Too many words.

Comment: The example in the question sounds a bit weird, as I would say "over" usually implies a certain distance, as in "over the crowd/room/fence/ocean", but putting a hand on someone suggests they are close.

Answer (score 0):

Using "over" serves to make the sentence more specific. If the author had simply written that "Bran looked at his bastard brother", without further context, Bran could be looking in some other direction, rather than "over" at the specific brother who is beside him on the horse. I don't think it is super important that the author used "over" here, however, the sentence without "over" leaves something to be desired.

In short, the use of the word "over" specifies the exact direction Bran is looking.

Comment: I think the explanations of Greybeard and Jason Bassford are good as far as my question goes. But what you say makes sense, too, from a writing point of view.